# Couldn't match type IO with Map and couldn't match type Map with [Char]

Tags: haskell, types

I am new to Haskell and the following code is giving me two errors:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import System.IO
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe

main = do
    return ()

getPhonebook :: Int -> (Map.Map String String)
getPhonebook n
    | n == 0 = Map.empty
    | otherwise = do
        line <- getLine
        let split = words line
        return (Map.insert (split !! 0) (split !! 1) (getPhonebook (n-1)))
```

The first error is on the line `line <- getLine`. The error says `Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Map.Map String’`. I don't understand this error, probably a silly mistake.

The second error is on the return line. It says `Couldn't match type ‘Map.Map String String’ with ‘[Char]’`, and the expected type is `[Char]`. I don't understand this since the function is supposed to return a Map and yet it is asking for a `[Char]`.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing pure with impure code - this might work out in less strict programming languages but haskell makes you "tag" every usage of `IO` - by putting you in the IO monad (there are unsafe ways around that - so let us not concern us with those).

You are promising to GHC - `getPhonebook :: Int -> (Map.Map String String)`
which means for every `Int` in the domain of getPhonebook - you will return a `(Map String String)` - pureley without any user input.

Now in the function body you do not fulfill this promise by using `getLine` and so on.

So let us change the type and acknowledge the use of IO.

```
getPhonebook :: Int -> IO (Map.Map String String)
```

Now your base case is not matching up to be an IO action, but this can be  fixed easily by using `return ...`.

But still GHC spots one problem - `Map.insert` is pure and good and won't accept `getPhonebook (n-1)` as this is now an IO action. How to solve this - binding this action to a name `previousPB <- getPhonebook (n-1)`.

Putting this together we get the following code:

```
getPhonebook :: Int -> IO (Map.Map String String)
getPhonebook n
  | n == 0 = return Map.empty
  | otherwise = do
        line <- getLine
        let split = words line
        previousPB <- getPhonebook (n-1)
        return $ Map.insert (split !! 0) (split !! 1) previousPB
```

now the question what the heck does this do - it fills a phone book by asking you for `n` entries and returns this to you - is this what you want it to do?  - I don't know!

Comment: Thanks, I'm just getting into Haskell and I thought doing a couple simple things would help me learn, and clearly it worked...